# City Suburbs Polygon using OSMNX

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geometry, geopandas, osmnx

I am trying to do something similar to the question [OSMNX - City Suburbs Polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386442/osmnx-city-suburbs-polygons). The city of Panama, in the Republic of Panama, is composed of corregimientos (like a borough). I am trying to get the boroughs within the red circle with a query in OSMNX:

```
place_names = [
"San Felipe, Panama, Panama",
"El Chorrillo, Panama, Panama",
"Santa Ana, Panama, Panama",
"Calidonia, Panama, Panama",
"Curundu, Panama, Panama",
# "Ancon, Panama, Panama",
"Bella Vista, Panama, Panama",
"Bethania, Panama, Panama",
"San Francisco, Panama, Panama",
"Pueblo Nuevo, Panama, Panama",
"Parque Lefevre, Panama, Panama",
"Rio Abajo, Panama, Panama",
```

]

[image: wikipedia image with Panama City boroughs]

This is the plot of what is returned from that query:

[image: plot of boroughs returned from my query]

Bethania returns the information for a park in the borough. I have been editing the Open Street Relation for the neighborhood to try to get it to show up in my query without success. In the code below, the query by_osmid for Bella Vista succeeds, and the one for Bethania fails. I have been editing the relation in Open Street Map trying to fix it but haven't managed it yet. Any ideas of why that is?

```
# get the boundary polygon for manhattan, project it, and plot it
# city = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Manhattan, New York, USA")
# city = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Bethania, Panama, Panama")
city = ox.geocode_to_gdf(["R11381324"], by_osmid=True) # Bella Vista succeeds
city = ox.geocode_to_gdf(["R11385188"], by_osmid=True) # Bethania *fails*
city_proj = ox.project_gdf(city)
ax = city_proj.plot(fc="gray", ec="none")
_ = ax.axis("off")
```

[image: Corrected boroughs image]

Comment: Got it! The edits worked. Changed and added tags: type: multipolygon, area: yes, boundary: administrative:

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The edits worked. Changed and added tags in Open Street Maps:

type: multipolygon,

area: yes,

boundary: administrative.

With those edits the query managed to succeed. I had to wait a while for the updates to make a difference when queried through OSMNX.